# Using while loop to add elements in a list without overwriting previous elements

Tags: python

I'm working with events and database classes.

I created a while loop that will keep appending my event (objects) in my database.
Also there is a command that will keep running in the if main block as long as the user doesn't type the command "exit".

My problem is that whenever the command asks for an event to be added, the previous gets erased per iteration.

The word "event" acts like the command "exit" So whenever this word is typed along with an event string (I've already implemented a function that will convert event strings to event objects). It will keep adding an event object into the Database.

```
def parse(command):
    '''Parse a command string.'''
# gist of event class Event(description, time, date, duration) not part of this function event string could be: '"Movie night" today 10:00pm'

    store_event = Database() # where I should save my event objects
    cmd_str = command.split() 
    a_lst =[]

    while cmd_str[0] == "event": #while event is a command that the user wants
        cmd_str = command.split()
        cmd_str.pop(0) # I don't need the word "event" just the event string after it.
        new_str = ' '.join(cmd_str)
        an_event = parseevent(new_str) # converts string object to event objects
        a_lst.append(an_event)
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code (aside from doing `cmd_str = command.split()` twice). Please explain more clearly what your input is, what result you get, and how that result differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do that:

```
def parse(command, a_lst):
    '''Parse a command string.'''
    a,b = command.split(None,1)
    if a == "event":
        a_lst.append(b)


store_event = Database() # where I should save my event objects
parse('event blahblahbla',store_event)
parse('event youtchouiya',store_event)
parse('event print ramantiyi',store_event)
parse('event import re',store_event)
# etc etc
```